# Can't login after devise upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I tried upgrading my devise gem from 2.1.2 to 2.1.3. 
After the upgrade I wasn't able to log in.
The logs only displayed me a 401 unauthorized message, no exceptions stack trace.

This is the login form I use:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .mail
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email

  .pwd
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password

  - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
    .remember
      = f.check_box :remember_me
      = f.label :remember_me

  .submit
    = f.submit t('login.submit')
```

I also tried upgrading to other version but with the same result. 
Also removing protect_from_forgery from my application_controller didn't help.
Currently I'm using Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3-p194.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: same is happening to me.. i upgraded to devise 2.2.3m rails 3.1.11 and ruby 1.9.3, im getting 401 on username and pass that worked before.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar experiences with Devise. It would usually boil down to Devise changing the encrypting algorithm.

Check the selected encryption type in either application or devise config file.  (bcrypt or sha are the usual suspects here)